# Android MediaPlayer Freezes when Screen Off

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, freeze

I have written a music player app that uses MediaPlayer to play MP3 files. It works fine most of the time but when I turn off the screen on my phone the prepare() method can freeze until I switch the screen on. As soon as the screen is turned on, away it goes.

This is quite frustrating because it doesn't always happen but happens after playing approx 3 tunes with the screen turned off. I don't get any exceptions.

```
mMediaPlayer.reset();

LogDebugf(  "MP3_PLAY::mMediaPlayer.setDataSource..\n" );
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource( mMP3Path );

LogDebugf(  "MP3_PLAY::mMediaPlayer.prepare..\n" );
mMediaPlayer.prepare();

// Can freeze for long times or until screen turned on in above call
LogDebugf(  "MP3_PLAY::mMediaPlayer.start..\n" );
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

My actual Logcat is shown below:

```
03-09 08:04:07.333 I/System.out( 8186): MP3_PLAY::mMediaPlayer.prepare..
03-09 08:04:07.333 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): setVideoSurfaceTexture
// Notice the huge delay here until I switch the screen on
03-09 08:04:31.049 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): prepare
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
03-09 08:04:31.059 W/MediaPlayer( 8186): info/warning (973, 0)
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): callback application
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): back from callback
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): New video size 0 x 0
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): callback application
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): back from callback
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): prepared
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): signal application thread
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): callback application
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): prepare complete - status=0
03-09 08:04:31.059 V/MediaPlayer( 8186): back from callback
03-09 08:04:31.059 I/System.out( 8186): MP3_PLAY::mMediaPlayer.start..
```

The last line that appears before the freeze is "setVideoSurfaceTexture" and then 'prepare' isn't processed until I turn the screen on ~30 seconds later.

UPDATE: I have even tried prepareAsync() and it has the same problem. This is on a Samsung Galaxy S4. I may give ExoPlayer a try instead if I cannot get this working reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the missing line below solved my problem:

```
mMediaPlayer.setWakeMode( getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK );
```

BUT..

Worse still, after I reboot my phone, I cannot play any music at all with the above change!

Now I get:

```
03-10 18:29:09.857 V/MediaPlayer( 2119): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
03-10 18:29:09.857 E/MediaPlayer( 2119): error (1, -2147483648)
03-10 18:29:09.857 V/MediaPlayer( 2119): callback application
03-10 18:29:09.857 V/MediaPlayer( 2119): back from callback
03-10 18:29:09.877 I/MediaPlayer( 2119): send context aware event
03-10 18:29:09.877 I/MediaPlayer( 2119): sendBroadcast CONTEXT_AWARE_MUSIC_INFO - type(error) - id (4)
03-10 18:29:09.877 E/MediaPlayer( 2119): Error (1,-2147483648)
03-10 18:29:09.877 I/System.out( 2119): OnErrorListener::MP3 ERROR 1 -2147483648
```

It would appear that I needed to wait for my phone to become ready before the MediaPlayer would work. It wouldn't even beep when selecting items until it woke up fully.